# Why vb stop execute some code and skip it

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, authentication

Im create a login form on vb.net and connect it to ms access database. The connection was succeed but while i tried to login with id and password i create on ms access , it failed. Im already test it with running with step into so i can know why it error.

im using visual studio 2010 and ms access 2013.

This is my login form code :

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ok.Click
        Try
            userss = user.Text
            Query = "Select * FROM user WHERE users = '" & userss & "' AND password = '" & pass.Text & "'"
            daData = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, conn)
            dsData = New DataSet
            daData.Fill(dsData) '**LAST EXECUTE CODE**
            If dsData.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0 Then '**VB DONT EXECUTE** 
                If mCount < 3 Then
                    MsgBox("Wrong Username or Password", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Message")
                    user.Focus()
                    mCount = mCount + 1
                    Me.pass.Text = ""
                Else
                    MsgBox("Login Failed", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Message")
                    End
                End If
            Else
                If (dsData.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(4) = 1) Then
                    dsData.Dispose()
                    dsData.Reset()
                    daData.Dispose()
                    Me.Hide()
                    Main.Show()
                Else
                    MsgBox("Login Failed", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Message")
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Database Connection Failed!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "Message") '**AND DIRECTLY EXECUTE HERE**
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message that `ex` contains?

Answer (score 0):

*Password* is a reserved word, so it needs brackets:

```
Query = "Select * FROM user WHERE users = '" & userss & "' AND [password] = '" & pass.Text & "'"
```

> Side note: Your use of singularis and pluralis for *user* is quite
>   confusing.